# how to initialize variable with iterator inside a loop in java?

Tags: java, loops, variables, iterator

Is it possible to initialize variable with iterator inside a loop ?

Example:

```
For (int i =0 ; i<3; i++){

String var[i] = "Something"+i;

}

System.out.print(var1);
System.out.print(var2);
System.out.print(var3);
```

Output:

```
"Something1"
"Something2"
"Something3"
```

Comment: Seems you're looking for an **array**. Check your Java learning guide, it should have a section about arrays.

Comment: Next time, please make sure to post valid Java code. `For` is not a Java keyword, `for` is.

Comment: Please do check your code for errors before posting here as a question. You can use online compiler like this one  - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php

Answer (score 1):

You have to work a lot on your basics, buddy.
The code above is messed up. Still, I will help you with the working code for this use case.

To answer to your question. Yes, it is possible to initialise variable with iterator inside loop. You can do it as follows:

```
String var[] = new String[3];

for(int i =0 ; i<3; i++){
    var[i] = "Something"+i;
}

System.out.print(var[1]);
System.out.print(var[2]);
System.out.print(var[3]);
```

I kept it simple for you to understand.
Do read the comments below for better-optimized code.
Happy coding!

Comment: Should just print var[i] in the loop.

Comment: Please use `String[] var` instead of `String var[]`. The latter comes from C, but is discouraged.

Comment: Also use println instead of print

Comment: Thanks a lot fellas! The person who asked the question appears to be a newbie. So, I had minimal changes for him to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't mean it like an array. 
I literally mean a new String variable. 
Like Var1, Var2 & Var3